# Register Sentencetransformer model on Azure ML

Tags: pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, sentence-transformers

Basically title. The Azure documentation for v2 is constantly getting updated, and as of now i have no resource to find out how you can register a pre-trained model from SentenceTransformers on AzureML for future use in endpoints. The library is based on Pytorch, but so far I've had no luck in using MLFlow(mentioned in the docs) to register it.

I don't have much code to show, so any help whatsoever would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MLFlow, you have to first save or log your model before you can register it. But with `log_model` you can do both in one step

```py
  mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, "my_model_path", registered_model_name="fancy")
```

Then it is easiest to deploy it from the AzureML Studio:
[image]

Comment: Thank you :) This is the correct answer, but of course I forgot to mention that I want a custom endpoint. Is it then possible to deploy your own endpoint with a custom scoring script with the SDK like the docs show? 

Because an annoying issue with MLFlowmodels and deployment through AzureML Studio is that it you don't get an option to upload your own scoring file, and Azure simply generates one for you...

Comment: Since I got you here, how would I go about fetching data during initialization of said endpoint? I have a dataset of embeddings that needs to be fetched for the endpoint. Does this require a different authorization compared to what you would do for say a data-prep job? Because using DefaultCredentials works just fine when creating the ML Client for the job, but in the endpoint, it crashes saying that "cannot import name TokenCredential from azure.core.credentials". Haven't found any record of this issue, so kinda in the dark :)

Comment: I should add that the embeddings are stored as a dataset on Azure ML